# Can OS of the servers hosting SharePoint and OS of the Server hosting SQL be different?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

Can Operating System of the servers hosting SharePoint and operating system of the Server hosting SQL be different?

For example:

- Windows 2008 R2 - SharePoint Hosted Servers
- Windows 2012 - SQL Server hosted Server.

Can a SharePoint Farm work in this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be different. The only general advice is that the OSes running SharePoint not be different.